# Software to control the amps output through USB

Tags: usb, charging

I have a 2014 MBP, and I'm trying to set it so I can charge my phone off the USB. I know it's 3.0 because it is capable of 1000mA in this cropped screenshot of my System Information:
[image: cropped screengrab of System Information]
But it's claiming it's only requested 500mA which I know is BS because my phones says "Charging Slowly"

Apple hates Google, idgaf, is there a way I can control the Current Required or Extra Operating Current or something?

I am not going to buy some obscure specific $30 adapter, that's not the point of this. I am not going to use a USB-Y cable, that's not the point, and I'll lose a perfectly good USB port, leaving me with zero. All I'm looking for is some software to control the output.

Comment: lol well my iPhone is also 500, guess Apple hates Apple. XD

Answer (score 1):

From [Apple Support page on USB devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201163#4):

> USB 3 devices can use up to 900mA of power (compared to 500mA used by USB 2 devices). You'll need to use a USB 3 cable to use the 900mA of power available. USB 2 cables don't support 900mA.

Your connector cable and device most likely use USB 2 interface. Not sure what phone you have, but as a side note all Apple devices and cables use USB 2 interface. This is a hardware limit, so the answer to your question is no, there is no software that can bypass the limit.

Comment: Nexus 6P, I'm using the supplied USB-C 3.0 cable, and the phone itself is USB-C 3.0. I don't understand how a 2.0 cable wouldn't support the amps anyway, unless it's just that shittily designed deliberately.